# How to convert htmlentities to normal text

Tags: php, html, html-entities, htmlspecialchars

I want to convert my string to normal text but I can't do that this...

My string:

```
Keen&#39;v feat Lorelei B - la vie du bon cot&eacute; ( clip officiel )
```

To convert it, I have used the htmlspecialchars_decode() function, but I have weird output:

```
Keen&#39;v feat Lorelei B - la vie du bon cotÃ© ( clip officiel )
```

Have you an idea to fix this ?

Thanks you.
Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) opposed to `htmlspecialchars_decode()`.

If you have passed any arguments into `htmlentities()`, such as the `$encoding` parameter, make sure to pass the same value to `html_entity_decode()` as well.